# Windows Systems Programming: Can a keystroke be sent to an open application that is not the currently active one?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system, keystroke

I'm a bit rusty on my Windows system programming...

Is it possible for a program to send a keystroke (I'm guessing by `SendMessage()` api call) to another application, if the (open) target application does not currently have the focus?  If it is possible, does it then make the target application become the active application, or does it still remain in the background?

Thanks in advance for any info you may be able to provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From memory: Yes, No.

You are looking for WM_KEYDOWN:

```
PostMessage(hwndOther, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ENTER, 0);
```

Comment: Don't think that's correct. The target window will also be expecting WM_KEYDOWN for one thing.

Comment: PostMessage() does work, just tried it.  MarkJ, not sure what you mean by "target window will also be expecting WM_KEYDOWN"?  It's contained there right in the 2nd parameter of PostMessage.

Comment: I'm guessing he meant WM_KEYUP - but it's pretty obvious when an app cares about getting a matching up. I was building a test for PostMessage(), just in case my memory failed me, but I got sidetracked :(.

Comment: for what i remember of 10 years ago OWL experience :-) WM_KEYxxx are used for gaming, shift-like keys and such. WM_CHAR is better be used for text entering.

Answer (score 1):

No, It will not change the focus, unless subsequent calls do setfocus. It will remain the same window order

Answer (score 1):

```
PostMessage(hwndOther, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_ENTER, 0);
```

This works for me, but only under Windows XP.

But On Vista and Windows 7 I've too got problem. Propably with UIPI.
I am trying to send a message to process from a DLL injected to this process.

How to fix it?

Comment: I can confirm that this doesn't work anymore in Windows 8 - I should check to see if WM_KEY* or WM_CHAR actually gets sent message or it's just the EDIT control in Notepad that wants to have focus....

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can send keystrokes, no it won't bring the other window to the top.

- One way is to use the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) API function - here's an [example of how to use it](http://vb.mvps.org/samples/project.asp?id=sendinput) in VB6 (ulp!).
- Probably easier to use [GUI Automation](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/ms747327.aspx) which is supported directly from .NET Framework 3.0 - for instance read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163465.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I'm familiar with SendKeys() from VB/VBA.  The problem is that it only sends keys to the active app, hence the need to roll my own version.  The .NET link looks interesting, will look into it further.

Comment: The first link doesn't use the native VB SendKeys, it's a replacement using the API call SendInput, so it doesn't have that limitation.

Comment: Alas, it *does* have the limitation since the SendInput() api call which it uses has the same limitation of the keystroke being to "sent to the foreground application." - found by checking the msdn info for SendInput()...about to investigate PostMessage() as suggested above...

Comment: PostMessage() as suggested by Simon Buchan is the one to use...have tested it with Notepad and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For a directed send of keystrokes, SendInput is the native method of choice, though it is subject to UIPI (integrity level) checks on Vista/2008/W7. You can't send keystrokes to an app that has an IL > yours.

A more general solution for capturing and redirecting input is a global keyboard hook (See the help for SetWindowsHookEx). But this is fairly hairy stuff - you have to cope with how you send the keystrokes on, you affect every process in the system because your code is effectively inserted in the input stream, it involves writing a native DLL... you have to know exactly what you're doing.

We use a global keyboard hook in our system (I wrote it), but we're a special case - a single function emergency call handling system. I wouldn't advise a global hook as a solution in general purpose Windows computing.

Comment: Cheers for responding and thanks for the heads up about Vista UIPI.  As I have subsequently found, SendInput() sends it to the foreground application. In the end, PostMessage() has worked for my simple needs. Note: UIPI applies also to PostMessage().

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SendInput() or hooks

The answer with PostMessage is wrong.

You must attach remotely your thread. See on [Win32 api Group](http://news://nntp.aioe.org/comp.os.ms-windows.programmer.win32) where it's a very classic question (C code, right MS method)

Comment: Broken link, and a bit incomprehensible! He's asking how to send keystrokes - never heard of attaching thread to do that? Sometimes people attach thread in order to bring non-foreground window to the front but that's not what he's asking about.

Comment: He might be referring to AttachThreadInput()? That's completely different.